# permutations and disjoint cycles, the inverse.

Tags: permutations, inverse

What is the inverse to the permutation $A = (2 4 6)(3 5)$ in $S_{6}$?

I got the inverse as $(2 5 6 4)$, but it's wrong?

Comment: This is  your second such question in half an hour, each time showing no work. This is not a site where we do your homework for you. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2779233/permutations-and-disjoint-cycles-how-do-you-do.

Answer (score 4):

To find the inverse of a permutation you simply reverse the cycles.

So, given $A=(2\ 4\ 6)(3\ 5)$; we have that $$A^{-1}=(6\ 4\ 2)(5\ 3).$$ *Note that the inverse of a $2$-cycle is just the $2$-cycle itself.*

---

Observe that $A=(2\ 4\ 6)(3\ 5)$ in its two line notation form is \begin{equation}
A= \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6 \\
1\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 3\ 2\\
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation}

Now, to find the inverse; we take the bottom row and put it in ascending order and see what we get. So \begin{equation}
A^{-1}= \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6 \\
1\ 6\ 5\ 2\ 3\ 4\\
\end{array}\right),
\end{equation}

which, in disjoint cycle notation, corresponds to $$(1)(2\ 6\ 4)(3\ 5).$$

Comment: How did you come up with that? Do you wanna show the steps?

Comment: @thesmallprint I am glad you want to help people by answering on this site. In general, though, I expect questioners to do as much of their own work as possible before coming here, so I don't like answering this kind of question right away. If you do want to, consider just supplying a hint.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, I do see what you mean. In this case, I thought since the answer was so short - I just thought I might as well supply it. But in the future I will consider just giving a hint as you say.